# Is there a Mocha equivalent of Rspec’s “mock().as_null_object”?

Tags: ruby, testing, frameworks, rspec2, ruby-mocha

Is there a Mocha equivalent of Rspec’s “mock().as_null_object”?

Answer (score 16):

Yes. Use “stub_everything()”

Documented here: http://mocha.rubyforge.org/classes/Mocha/API.html#M000004.

Comment: `stub_everything`  always returns nil, `as_null_object` always returns the stub, so they aren't quite the same